# InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)

Tags: python, python-requests

I was able to gather data from a web page using this

```
import requests
import lxml.html
import re
url = "http://animesora.com/flying-witch-episode-7-english-subtitle/"
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.content
dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(page)

for link in dom.xpath('//div[@class="downloadarea"]//a/@href'):
    down = re.findall('https://.*',link)     
    print (down)
```

when I try this to gather more data on the results of the above code I was presented with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sven/PycharmProjects/untitled1/.idea/test4.py", line 21, in <module>
    r2 = requests.get(down)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 672, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://link.safelinkconverter.com/review.php?id=aHR0cDovLygqKC5fKC9zTGZYZ0s=&c=1&user=51757']'
```

This is the code I was using:

```
for link2 in down:
    r2 = requests.get(down)
    page2 = r.url
    dom2 = lxml.html.fromstring(page2)

for link2 in dom2('//div[@class="button green"]//onclick'):

    down2 = re.findall('.*',down2)
    print (down2)
```

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of the exception. You only gave us a *partial* exception message, truncating it at the point where the URL is being named that failed. There is more data after `were found for '`, with at least one more `'` following, for example.

Comment: Why are you using a regex? Also you can see pretty clearly that the url is inside a list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i have no idea it is regex. i just saw that here in stackoverflow then modified it

Comment: @pandelemon, there is absolutely no need for a regex, what are you actually trying to get from the page?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the *whole list*:

```
for link2 in down:
    r2 = requests.get(down)
```

Note how you passed in `down`, *not* `link2`. `down` is a list, not a single URL string.

Pass in `link2`:

```
for link2 in down:
    r2 = requests.get(link2)
```

I'm not sure why you are using regular expressions. In the loop

```
for link in dom.xpath('//div[@class="downloadarea"]//a/@href'):
```

each `link` is *already* a fully qualified URL:

```
>>> for link in dom.xpath('//div[@class="downloadarea"]//a/@href'):
...     print link
...
https://link.safelinkconverter.com/review.php?id=aHR0cDovLygqKC5fKC9FZEk2Qg==&c=1&user=51757
https://link.safelinkconverter.com/review.php?id=aHR0cDovLygqKC5fKC95Tmg2Qg==&c=1&user=51757
https://link.safelinkconverter.com/review.php?id=aHR0cDovLygqKC5fKC93dFBmVFg=&c=1&user=51757
https://link.safelinkconverter.com/review.php?id=aHR0cDovLygqKC5fKC9zTGZYZ0s=&c=1&user=51757
```

You don't need to do any further processing on that.

Your remaining code has more errors; you confused `r2.url` with `r2.content`, and forgot the `.xpath` part in your `dom2.xpath(...)` query.

Comment: should i save this as a file the open them from there?

Comment: @pandelemon: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Martin Pieters my output should be something like this ***http***://ouo.io

Comment: @pandelemon: sorry, this is not how this site works; we can answer *specific questions* only, not help fix every single issue after that. If you don't fully understand what your own code does yet, you may want to study Python programming some more.

Comment: @Martin Pieters thanks a lot. i just tried it today. you are a great help