# Using Stanford Tregex in Python for German text

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, tree, stanford-nlp, subtree

The accepted answer in
[Using Stanford Tregex in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802406/using-stanford-tregex-in-python)
is almost solving my problem, but I don't know how to set the language to German. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if when you start the server you add `-serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties`.  Let me know if that doesn't work.  Also make sure you have the German models jar on your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm quite a beginnger in Python, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "when you start the server". My code starts with url = "...", then request_params = ... and so on. Do I have to check the settings of the installation of CoreNLP on the server?

Comment: How are you starting the Java server?  What Python interface are you using?  The Stack Overflow example you cited has a part where you start the server with a  Java command.  That is where you add the extra property to specify German settings.

Comment: Also, I'd suggesting using this Python library for accessing the server in Python. https://github.com/stanfordnlp/python-stanford-corenlp