# Stanford Core NLP use tokensRegex

Tags: stanford-nlp

Let's take the following"

```
client = CoreNLPClient(memory='1G', threads=1, annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner','depparse'], timeout=1000)
ann = client.annotate('Wow a nice sentence here')
sentence = ann.sentence[0]
```

Then I process the tags, dependencies, etc. but I also want to use `TokensRegex` to extract specific words. I saw the answer using `requests` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802406/using-stanford-tregex-in-python)) however it seems odd to have to send another request (and do the tagging again) in order to use `TokensRegex`. Can we just use the already annotated `sentence` with TokensRegex?

**Edit**
I see that we can use `client.tokensregex('Wow a nice sentence here', <pattern>`) however this still has to send a request again I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `tokensregex` annotator that you can place at the end of your pipeline that will run rules.

See here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html