# My script throws an error when I make a go using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I've created a script in python using `multiprocessing` library to scrape certain fields from a webpage. As I don't have any knowledge as to how I can make a go using `multiprocessing` I get an error when I execute the below script:

```
import requests 
from lxml.html import fromstring
from multiprocessing import Process

link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}"

def create_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    tree = fromstring(response)
    for title in tree.cssselect("div.info"):
        name = title.cssselect("a.business-name span")[0].text
        street = title.cssselect("span.street-address")[0].text
        try:
            phone = title.cssselect("div[class^=phones]")[0].text
        except IndexError:
            phone = ""
        print(name, street, phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = [link.format(page) for page in range(4)]
    p = Process(target=create_links, args=(links,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Error I'm having:

```
722, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
```

I'm getting that error because the script considers the list of links as an individual link whereas I knew I had to pass list of links within `args=(links,)`. How may I run it successfully?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212867/invalidschemano-connection-adapters-were-found-for-s-url

Comment: I've never been able to get good performance with python and threads, I imagine it depend partly on platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine with Pool

```
import requests 
from lxml.html import fromstring
from multiprocessing import Pool

link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}"

def create_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    tree = fromstring(response)
    for title in tree.cssselect("div.info"):
        name = title.cssselect("a.business-name span")[0].text
        street = title.cssselect("span.street-address")[0].text
        try:
            phone = title.cssselect("div[class^=phones]")[0].text
        except IndexError:
            phone = ""
        print(name, street, phone)


links = [link.format(page) for page in range(4)]

def main():
    with Pool(4) as p:
        print(p.map(create_links, links))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
Caffe Latte 6254 Wilshire Blvd (323) 936-5213
Bourgeois Pig 5931 Franklin Ave (323) 464-6008
Beard Papa Sweet Cafe 6801 Hollywood Blvd Ste 157 (323) 462-6100
Intelligentsia Coffee 3922 W Sunset Blvd (323) 663-6173
The Downbeat Cafe 1202 N Alvarado St (213) 483-3955
Sabor Y Cultura 5625 Hollywood Blvd (323) 466-0481
The Wood Cafe 12000 Washington Pl (310) 915-9663
Groundwork Coffee Inc 1501 N Cahuenga Blvd (323) 871-0143
The Apple Pan 10801 W Pico Blvd (310) 475-3585
Good Microbrew & Grill 3725 W Sunset Blvd (323) 660-3645
The Standard Hollywood 8300 W Sunset Blvd (323) 650-9090
```

Comment: Both of the solutions are working. I've got a question on yours' though. Ain't it necessary to use somewhere `.join()` command like `p.join()` or something?

Comment: No need to join anything.

Comment: I am getting [None, None, None, None]  when running this in Spyder. Is there something I may be missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pool from multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

and specify processes as

```
links = [link.format(page) for page in range(4)]
p = Pool(10)  # number of process at a time
link = p.map(parse, links)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to stick to `Process` then the following should work:

```
import requests 
from lxml.html import fromstring
from multiprocessing import Process

link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}"

def create_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    tree = fromstring(response)
    for title in tree.cssselect("div.info"):
        name = title.cssselect("a.business-name span")[0].text
        try:
            street = title.cssselect("span.street-address")[0].text
        except IndexError: street = ""
        try:
            phone = title.cssselect("div[class^=phones]")[0].text
        except IndexError: phone = ""
        print(name, street, phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = []
    for links in [link.format(page) for page in range(1,6)]:
        p = Process(target=create_links, args=(links,))
        items.append(p)
        p.start()

    for process in items:
        process.join()
```

Comment: Finally worked out which environment I could run the above in. +